# How to log events using EventNotifierSupport in Apache Camel version 3.4.2?

Tags: java, apache-camel

Background:
I am migrating my code from camel 2.24.1 to 3.4.2. I have a custom event notifier which was using the log field provided by EventNotifierSupport Class for logging events. When upgrading to version 3.4.2. The log field is no longer available.
[Sample as to what I have](https://people.apache.org/%7Edkulp/camel/eventnotifier-to-log-details-about-all-sent-exchanges.html)

Question: How can I log events with the EventNotifierSupport Class on version 3.4.2. If not, what is the alternative ?

[EventNotifierSupport ver 2.24.1](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.24.1/org/apache/camel/support/EventNotifierSupport.html)
[EventNotifierSupport ver 3.4.2](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-support/3.4.2/org/apache/camel/support/EventNotifierSupport.html)

Answer (score 0):

You just add your own LOG field if its for logging with your logging framework of choice.